# R error: Wrong length for a vector, should be 2

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, lapply, sapply

Here is a gist of what I want to do:

I've got 2 data frames:
x (id is unique)

```
id          timestamp
282462839   2012-12-05 10:55:00
282462992   2012-12-05 12:08:00
282462740   2012-12-05 12:13:00
282462999   2012-12-05 12:48:00
```

y (id is not unique)

```
id          value1    value2
282462839   300       100
282462839   300       200
282462839   400       300
282462999   500       400
282462999   300       150
```

I also have a function myfunc(id,pvalue) that computes something and returns one of the value2 values depending on pvalue and other value1s (more complicated than just pvalue==value1)

I want to create a 3rd column for x that contains the corresponding computed myfunc(id,pvalue), where pvalue is an integer that is constant(say 20).

so in essence, I want to do this:

```
x$t20 <- myfunc(x$id,20)
```

I tried using lappy and sapply this way:

```
x$t20 <- sapply(as.vector(x$id),myfunc,pvalue=20)
```

I tried using lapply and without the as.vector as well, but I kept getting this error:

```
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p2) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
```

It works when I just give mean where it just replicates $id in $t20.

How do I do this?

EDIT 1:
Here's a skeleton of myfunc:

```
myfunc <- function(xid,pvalue) {
  result <- subset(y,id==xid)
  retVal <- -1
  if(nrow(result) < 12){
    return(NaN)
  }
  for(i in (1:nrow(result))){
    #code to process result
  }
  return(retVal)
}
```

Comment: If your function `myfunc` is vectorized `x$t20 <- myfunc(x$id, 20)` should return what you want.

Comment: If I do that, it gives me an error:
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p2) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
In addition: Warning message:
In id == xid :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

my actual definition is myfunc(xid,pvalue) 

There is a line where i do:
result <- subset(y,id==xid)

I tried changing it to xid[1] but that still gave the vector length should be 2 error

Comment: It seems that the problem is in function, please edit your post and add the code of `myfunc`.

Comment: Please give your complete function and make your code reproducible to enable testing. The `for` loop in your function makes me suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very difficult to help without full code, but here are some tips. First you can obtain the logical vector of id's which should be processed, then use vectorized `ifelse` statment.

```
tmp <- table(y$id) >= 12
y$t20 <- ifelse(tmp[as.character(y$id)], your_new_func(), NaN)
```

Comment: Oh! Since there was no detailed explanation in R about where the error occured I was assuming it was something to do with either passing the argument or the subset part! I think I found out where the error occured! It didnt strike me that it could be with the internals of the function! Thank you so much!

Comment: The error probably is caused by your code which you hid, because your original function works for me and retuns only a warning message. In R it is better to avoid `for` loop and use vectorized functions.